# unregister Shake listener

Tags: android

I am using Shake Listener in one of my application.Now I want to know whether there is anyway to stop shake listener from my application, ie I want to stop the senser on button click. Can anybody suggest any useful way to stop it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720215/android-shakelistener-error

Comment: try this "sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
 sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
          sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
```